# ASP.NET - HTML.Display not displaying value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:

```
@model  IEnumerable<SampleMvcApp.Models.Exercise>



@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(m => m.DayName).Distinct())

{
    <table class="table">
    <h2>@Html.Display(item.Select(x => x.DayName).ToString())</h2>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ExerciseName
                </th>
                <th>
                    ExerciseTime
                </th>
                <th>
                    ExerciseRepetition
                </th>
                <th>
                    MomentOfTheDay
                </th>
                <th>
                    Routine
                </th>
                <th>
                    Week
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var test2 in item)
                {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.ExerciseName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.ExerciseTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.ExerciseRepetition)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.MomentOfTheDay)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.Routine.RoutineID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test2.ExerciseWeek)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@test2.ExerciseID">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@test2.ExerciseID">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@test2.ExerciseID">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
            }


    </table>

    }
```

Everything works fine but

```
   <h2>@Html.Display(item.Select(x => x.DayName).ToString())</h2>
```

I'm just trying to show the Day Name above the table as it is grouped by days, however the Display code won't show anything. I've tried using DisplayFor but apparently it doesn't accept expressions. Or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Display` is not intended for this purpose, which is why it doesn't work. What you need is `Html.DisplayFor`. However, the error you're getting with that is because the parameter must be an expression that evaluates to an member on the model. Using something like `Select` is not possible because the expression cannot be parsed to a particular member.

Now, given your use of `Select` here, it's not entirely clear what kind of display you're expecting to see. It's going to be an enumerable, so you'd need to make some decision about how each item in that enumerable should be handled. Simply, you could do something like:

```
<h2>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DayName)
    }
</h2>
```

However, since this is a heading, it's likely you're only expecting a single day name, so you might rather just do something like:

```
@{ var item = item.First(); }
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.DayName)</h2>
```

Yet, it's not entirely clear if `DisplayFor` is even necessary here. If `DayName` is just a string like `Monday`, then `DisplayFor` is entirely superfluous; it will merely just output the string. Therefore, you could just do:

```
<h2>@items.Select(x => x.DayName).First()</h2>
```

Comment: I almost had the correct approach haha. Thanks a lot for clearing that up.